# How to vectorize a function to reshape each element of a ndarray, where each element is a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function to generate a ndarrary of values from a ndarray of keys without altering shape or pattern:

```
# in_dict is the reference dictionary
# pattern is the ndarray which contains the pattern of keys
def reshape_to_array(in_dict, pattern):
    vec_func = np.vectorize(in_dict.get)
    return np.matrix(vec_func(pattern))
```

I have a ndarray of dictionaries where each element is like `in_dict`. I want to vectorize `reshape_to_array` function so that it can be applied on the ndarray of dictionaries.

N. B. the `pattern` is fixed for all the elements of the ndarry.

Comment: which python version are using?

Comment: Are you sure it's an ndarray and not just a list? Also, the `vectorize` method is something of a misnomer because it's really just a `for` loop.

Comment: I am using Python v3.7

Comment: Yes, It is a ndarray. Basically an image and the dictionary contains specific band values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800651/constructing-a-ndarray-of-values-from-another-ndarray-containing-dictionary-keys is question that recommended using `np.vectorize` to use the dictionary `get`.

Comment: `f = np.vectorize(lambda adict, pattern: return adict.get(pattern))` might work, which would  called as `f(dict_array, pat_array)`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. When I try it reports: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4) (2,2)